# Django - Following a foreign key relationship (i.e JOIN in SQL)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

Busy playing with django, but one thing seems to be tripping me up is following a foreign key relationship. Now, I have a ton of experience in writing SQL, so i could prob. return the result if the ORM was not there.

Basically this is the SQL query i want returned

```
Select
  table1.id
  table1.text
  table1.user
  table2.user_name
  table2.url
from table1, table2
where table1.user_id = table2.id
```

My model classes have been defined as:

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    #other fields
    text        = models.TextField()
    user        = models.ForeignKey('table2')

class Table2(models.Model):
    # other fields
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I have been through the documentation and reference for querysets, models and views on the django website. But its still not clear on how to do this.

I have also setup the url with a generic list view, but would like to access the *user_name* field from the second table in the template. I tried *select_related* in urls.py and also via the shell but it does not seem to work. See examples below.

config in urls

```
url(r'^$','django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', { 'queryset': Table1.objects.select_related() }),
```

At the shell

```
>>> a = Table1.objects.select_related().get(id=1)
>>> a.id
1
>>> a.user_name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Table1' object has no attribute 'user_name'
```

So basically,

- What am i doing wrong?
- Am i missing something?
- What's the best way to pass fields from two tables in the same queryset to your template (So fields from both tables can be accessed)
- Can this be done with generic views?

Comment: Argh, Feel silly figured it out. To include related fields in your template do this:

{{ object.id.<field from Table2>

Comment: to be clear in your template you should put
{{ object.<foreign key ID>.<Field from table 2> }}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
u = Table1.objects.get(id=1)
print u.id
print u.user.user_name
```

If you want to follow a foreign key, you must do it explicitly. You don't get an automatic join, when you retrieve an object from Table1. You will only get an object from Table2, when you access a foreign key field, which is user in this example

Comment: Thanks man, that seems to have worked. Though according to the docs the select_related option should return back the entire query(including joins).

how would you include all the fields in your url config?

Comment: I have never needed select_related yet - as freiksenet have written, it is provided if you need to boost up performance.

Also, why do you need to put any fields in urls already? Why don't you retrieve what you need in a view?

Comment: thanks man... got it working. Now i feel like a twob!

Your answer helped!

Comment: @Issy: Don't worry about `select_related` unless you're processing a huge query with multiple rows.  For onsie-twosie queries like yours, all the fields of a given row are fetched into cache together.

Answer (score 2):

select_related() do not add second table result directly to the query, it just "Loads" them, insead of giving to you lazily. You should only use it, when you are sure it can boost your site performance. To get second table you need to write

```
a.user.username
```

In Django to get related table you need to follow them through foreign-keys that you have designed. Query itself do not directly translate to SQL query, because it is "lazy". It will execute only SQL that you need and only when you need.

If you have `select_related` SQL would have been executed at the moment when you do original query for `a`. But if you didn't have `select_related` then it would load DB only when you actually execute `a.user.username`.